# How to show default "image" if the loaded image doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, io

I am making an application which a user can load an image via a certain path. Then, the path of the loaded image is stored, and the next time the user want to open the document again, then the image is loaded based on the path.

But, I want to handle, just in case the former path is invalid (image moved / deleted), then it's not an error committed, but, this kind of object showed :

[image]

I wonder if there is any way to make the application to do that without have that image. I mean, maybe C# have a certain property for that kind of "missing" image?

Thank you.

P.S. And, that "missing" image above is truly a "missing" image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `Converter` to do that for you. Add a property for you to be able to set the default `Image` path:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class EmptyImageToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an empty string value into the DefaultImagePath property value if it exists, or a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue otherwise.
    /// </summary>
    public string DefaultImagePath { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || targetType != typeof(ImageSource)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        string imagePath = value.ToString();
        return imagePath.IsNullOrEmpty() ? DefaultImagePath.IsNullOrEmpty() ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue : DefaultImagePath : imagePath;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<Converters:EmptyImageToImageSourceConverter x:Key="EmptyImageToImageSourceConverter" 
    DefaultImagePath="pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/DefaultImage.png" />
```

Please note that this `Converter` works with `string` file paths like the one above, rather than `BitMapImage` or `ImageSource` objects. It would also require you to provide a default image to display.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ImageFailed-Event of the Image Control.

If the Event is raised set the error Image there.

```
<Image src= ImageFailed="OnImageFailed" />
```